# Why is my object losing reference after a promise?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function which accepts an object called `issue`, and then calls a promise.  Any changes made to the object reference before the promise is executed will be reflected in the original reference.  Any changes made after it are not.  Why not and how can I fix it?

This example below illustrates the problem

```
angular.module('app').controller('IssueCtrl',['issues', function(issues){
   var issue = {};
   issue.id=1;
   issues.add_comment('test', issue).then(function(issue){
       console.log(issue.id);
   }
   // returns 'a'
}
]);


angular.module('app').factory('issues', function(){
  o.add_comment = function (comment, issue) {
      // Changes made before promise are reflected in original promise
      issue.id='a'
    return o.update(comment).then(function(new_comment){
      // Changes made after promise are not reflected in original promise
      issue.id = 'b'
      return new_comment
  }

  o.update=function(){
      // more code
  }
 return o;
});
```

Comment: Promise are asynchronous and you access `issue` before it change

Comment: you can't use `console.log` to troubleshoot asynchronous code;  in this case, the call to `console.log(issue.id)` is not blocked by the promise, so it outputs immediately after the promise is called, before the promise has returned and updated the data.

Comment: Forgot to include this in the codesample, edited

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
issues.add_comment(issue);
```

that function ends with

```
return o.update(comment).then(...
```

which returns a promise immediately, not after `then()` has executed. If you want to wait for that, you have to do so in your original call:

```
issues.add_comment(issue).then(....
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that when I downsampled the code.  Edit now, I do have a then() function included

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the line in your controller:

```
issues.add_comment('test', issue).then(function(issue){
   console.log(issue.id);
}
```

The service is returning a promise object, and eventually `new_comment`.  you are overwriting the original `issue` in the function signature.  Try something like this instead:

```
issues.add_comment('test', issue).then(function(resp){
   console.log('inside then', issue.id);
   console.log('then response', resp);
})
```

[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ews5CXxCHmyNiXhiUOa1?p=preview)